# passing parameters to find script

Tags: shell, find, exec, sh

I am attempting to use find and -exec to process files and want to call a shell script, but can't seem to figure out how to pass variables to that script:

```
DIR_TEMP='/tmp'
NAME='foo'
TARGET='/tmp/target'
find . -type f -name \*.ko.gz -exec /bin/sh -c ${DIR_TEMP}/${NAME}.sort "$TARGET" {} \;
```

Contents of /tmp/foo.sort

```
 #!/bin/sh
 echo "called, 0 :$0:, 1 :$1:, 2 :$2:" >> /tmp/debug.txt
```

All I seem to get is:

```
called, 0 :/tmp/foo.sort:, 1 ::, 2 ::
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-c` option takes *a single argument*, so instead of

```
/bin/sh -c ${DIR_TEMP}/${NAME}.sort "$TARGET" {}
```

do

```
/bin/sh -c "$DIR_TEMP/$NAME.sort $TARGET '{}'"
```

Comment: This may be a purely theoretical concern, but some implementations of find will not allow {} to be used this way.  For those, you can do `find ... -exec /bin/sh -c "$DIR_TEMP/$NAME.sort $TARGET \"$1\"" _ {} \;`

Comment: Good one William. You'd need to escape `\$1` to protect it though